# Mock location does not work in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

From reading [this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#extended), I tried to send gps location to the emulator, but it doesn't work. I tried with Google Maps.
The emulator info: Nexus 5, API Level 19, Kitkat 4.4

A screen shot: (click send but nothing happens)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mock location in your app, I don't think it will work google maps as it won't have permission to use mock location. You have to declare android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION in manifest.

Get the location using

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, 0, 0f, this);
        }
```