# How to set the location manually in Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-location, android-virtual-device

I have a project in which I need to get the location as India. But in my emulator I am not getting the location.

- I need to get the location as India
- when I take the google maps from my emulator, it is showing the current location in middle of the sea.

  ```
  API level I am using is 27.
  Emulator I use is Nexus 5x.
  ```

how to get the current position in this Emulator and also manually.

I tried to edit the location in Emulator and tried to give the latitude and longitude but it is not working.

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)

Comment: Check these Links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247350/emulators-location-simulation-not-working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204953/mock-location-does-not-work-in-android-studio-emulator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972114/set-gps-location-in-emulator-using-android-studio

Answer (score 27):

In 2020 with Android Studio 3.6, the way I had to change the emulator location is slightly different than accepted answer. Here how it is:

First,

[image: click more on emulator]

Second, **Location** is **first menu item** and it is selected by default. You have to select your location in the map and **save that point**.

[image: tap on map and set your location point]

Third, select the saved point and press on select location button in bottom right corner.

[image: change emulator location]

That's it, close that window. You are all done.

Sometimes you may have to close the emulator and open (Not restart).

Comment: You can set it visually but the longitude and latitude will still be somewhere in America if i log it inside my application

Comment: Yes, that is the Mountain View location after these changes yet

Comment: It is not working. It still gives Mountain View location.

Comment: I have only one location added, saved it and set it as SET Location.

Comment: Still not working after set a new location, I tried also with reset.

Comment: @A.Amini you must restart emulator to take effect

Comment: @SriramNadiminti, I also have this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354181/android-studio-emulator-first-transfers-to-mountain-view-location-in-google-maps. Have you fixed this behaviour?

Comment: @CoolMind - No. I couldn't.

Comment: @SriramNadiminti Did you tried closing and opening emulator after suggested steps?

Comment: @Blasanka. Yes I have. Even restarted the Android Studio

Comment: For me, closing the `Extended controls` window made it work

Answer (score 26):

First of all,

- Restart your emulator.
- Go to More > Location. Enter your lat-long > Press **SEND**

[image]

Comment: tried that many times.. doesn't works, after setting it when i look at google map its still says the current location is in  america

Comment: As of this writing, those location controls no longer exist in Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1.

Answer (score 5):

In my case; until i login my Google account on emulator, location not changed. After login, it's changed. I think it's about Google Services.

Comment: This worked for me, i just logged in with my google account on the emulator

Answer (score 4):

You can set Location using Command prompt or ADB

Set permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

Find the correct local port for your Android emulator:

```
$ adb devices
  List of devices attached
  emulator-5554 device
```

The port we are looking for is in this case 5554. Now connect via telnet:

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
  Trying::1...
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  Connected to localhost.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
```

Set your preferred location manually: You set the location with the geo fix command:

```
 geo fix $longitude $latitude
```

**For Example**

```
geo fix 2.169919 41.387917
OK
```

**ANOTHER EASY WAY**

Open **Android Device Monitor** From Android Studio.

Select the Emulator.

Select **Emulator Control**

In Emulator Control Select **Location Control**

Select **Manual**

In that Give your **Longitude** and **Latitude**

Comment: when i tried to give the command - geo fix 2.169919 41.387917 , iam getting error:-  Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in
'C:\Users\martin\.emulator_console_auth_token'
OK  - what to do with this error @Tomin B

Comment: @Martinj Try the next method. Using Android Device Monitor. Second Method will Work for Sure

Comment: when i clicked the android device monitor nothing comes

Comment: the ADM has everything grayed out for emulator control. the emulator lets you type and press buttons with gps coords, but it has no affect

Comment: @Martinj Ops forgot to say that you also need to restart emulator. Did you?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting the point and restarting the emulator, then signin in to Google account and checking my location in Chrome directly was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by wiping the emulator's data and restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

### Find the correct local port for your Android emulator:

```
$ adb devices
  List of devices attached
  emulator-5554 device
```

### The port we are looking for is in this case 5554. Now connect via telnet:

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
  Trying::1...
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  Connected to localhost.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
```

### Set your preferred location manually: You set the location with the geo fix command:

```
 geo fix $longitude $latitude
```

### For Example

```
geo fix 2.169919 41.387917
OK
```

### If you are having authentication required issue, then:

```
Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in
'C:\Users\Administrator\.emulator_console_auth_token' <--you will find your auth code here
OK
auth PsL*******QML <---pass auth with your authentication code then enter 
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
geo fix your_desired_long your_desired_lat <--then this
OK
```

### Or you can also do like this:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 emu geo fix <longitude> <latitude>
your emulator name-> like emulator-5554
adb -s emulator-5554 emu geo fix -122.0838 37.4220
```

Answer (score -1):

set force Android Location Manager to true. Like this **"position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition( desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low, forceAndroidLocationManager: true);"** then you will get the location on emulator.