# Mock location - Fake Gps Example

Tags: react-native, expo

how do I make fake gps with react-native or expo.
Can you give an example. Thank you...
I want the phone location to be shown where I want

Answer (score 0):

You will need another Apple device with the same Apple ID. Then enter Settings > Privacy > Sharing my location and select the second device.

Remember when you do it, the GPS location of the selected device will be used in a geographical location and should always be turned on!

In this case, only the location of the second device, the fake position, can be selected.

OR

android First of all,

Restart your emulator.
Go to More > Location. Enter your lat-long > Press SEND

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47530560/11212074