# Android Studio emulator first transfers to Googleplex (Mountain View) location in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, android-emulator, location, android-gps

I have an application where I set current location (using Google Maps). Every time I open Google Maps *inside the application* in Android Studio emulator, it sets location to Googleplex, Mountain View (latitude = 37.4220186, longitude = -122.0839727). The emulator is Nexus 5 having Android SDK 30.

[image]

If I change the location in [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528006/how-to-set-the-location-manually-in-android-studio-emulator/47530560) to `Moscow`, the emulator can relocate to `Moscow` after clicking `My location` button, but sometimes it doesn't relocate. Then, after clicking the second time it can transfer to `Mountain View` again (and then again to `Moscow` and so on).

It's an annoying behaviour. How to force Android Studio emulator to start in `Moscow`?

[image]

If I open `Google Maps` themselves in the emulator, it sets a right position in `Moscow`.

[image]

Comment: Currently I don't have a solution for this bug. But you can start `Google Maps` application and find your location there. Then turn to your application and start location search there. In this case it will find faster and more accurate.